# Downloading today's file from FTP server using WinSCP from batch file fails with "Mask is invalid near '=today'"

Tags: batch-file, ftp, command-line-arguments, winscp

I have a batch file that receives an argument then passes that argument to a text scrip file that invokes WinSCP to download a file.

My goal is to download today's file.

I am able to download the file if in the text script file I don't have `>=today`.

What do I need to change to download today's file, if it exists?

**Batch File**

```
set arg1=%1
set CurrentPath=C:\Temp\

rem drive
c:

rem folder do WinSCP
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP

rem Download file
winscp.exe /console /script=%CurrentPath%sftp.txt /parameter %arg1%
```

**Text script file**

```
option batch abort
option confirm off 

# Connect
open <.....> 

# Download file to
get %1%>=today "C:\Temp\"

# Disconnect
close
```

The error I'm getting:

> Mask is invalid near '=today'

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

As-Is

```
# Download file to
get %1%>=today "C:\Temp\"
```

To-Be

```
# Download file to
get -filemask= %1%"*>1D" "C:\Temp\"
```

Comment: `1D` (=24 hours) is not the same thing as `today`. And the syntax you have there is quite strange. `-filemask=` without any argument is noop.

Comment: @Martin Prikryl, because using an old version of WinSCP does not support the ``today`` keyword, I tried this way and it works. Do you know another way to make it work in an older version?

Comment: Well, it can work, but the empty `-filemask` and the quotes are noop, and the asterisk is almost noop and maybe even wrong, unless you meant the parameter to work as a prefix. So this does the same what your code: `get %1%*>1D "C:\Temp\"` and you might want to remove the asterisk too. + For `today` equivalent with an older version, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Your way is better and more clean! I tried ``get %1%*>1D "C:\Temp\"`` and it works, but ``get %1%>=%TIMESTAMP#yyyy-mm-dd% "C:\Temp\"`` did not worked. I had to put an ``*`` after ``%1%`` like this ``get %1%*>=%TIMESTAMP#yyyy-mm-dd% "C:\Temp\"`` to make it work. Can you tell me why?

Comment: I do not know what you pass to the batch file argument and what your file names are. So I cannot answer that. As I wrote before, the `*` would be needed, if what you pass to the argument is a *prefix*.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is about passing parameters.

But the [`today` keyword](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#today) is a "recent" feature (WinSCP 5.14 from October 2018). So you probably have an old version of WinSCP that does not support it.

---

If you do not have a version of WinSCP that supports `today`, you can use [`%TIMESTAMP%` pattern](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp):

```
get %1%>=%TIMESTAMP#yyyy-mm-dd% "C:\Temp\"
```

*Though you should always use the latest version of WinSCP, if you want to stay safe.*